# .gethostbyaddr() does not work on all devices. Why? (Python)

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, networking, ip-address, hostname

I wrote a script that goes through all local IPs in the '0' network (192.168.0.*).

I use a loop with `socket.gethostbyaddr(ip_modified_by_the_loop_each_time)`.

The loop returns me 3 devices their hostnames.
Now, I found that it does not find 4 devices (at least).

- It does wind my Windows Laptop, not my Android Phone. It does find
- one MacBook, not the iMac, not the other MacBook. It also does not
- find any phone.

I know that all the devices are online and have an IPv4 address.

I can ping them very well, it responds just fine. But when I use `socket.gethostbyaddr(ip_modified_by_the_loop_each_time)` it throws an error.

I used a `try:`/`except:` statement to get around the error, but it still can not find my phone by IP and get the hostname, but I know it is there. 
I am using python 3.3

Why is that happening, how to fix that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

gethostbyaddr tries to find out the hostname for a given IP address by using either locally stored information (i.e. `/etc/hosts`) or doing a reverse DNS lookup. The result does not depend on the host being online or not, they only depend on the availability of these information.

And these information can also not be trusted. For example the DNS operator of a domain could add the following records:

```
  test.example.com       A    public.ip.of.test
  public.ip.of.test      PTR  localhost.
```

In this case a lookup (`gethostbyname`) of `test.example.com` would return the IP address of this host while a reverse lookup (`gethostbyaddr`) would claim that the hostname is `localhost`. And if the PTR record would be missing `gethostbyaddr` would fail, even if the host is online.

See also [wikipedia: reverse dns lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup).